The latest Pac4J Play Framework 3 Java Demo does not compile / start
I cannot run the current Pac4J Play Framework 3 Java Demo from
https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo
Platform Debian 12 Bookworm
Java Version: openjdk 17.0.12 2024-07-16
Default project settings
[NoSuchMethodError: 'void play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter.$init$(play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter)']

org.pac4j.play.filters.SecurityFilter.<init>(SecurityFilter.scala:63)
org.pac4j.play.filters.SecurityFilter$$FastClassByGuice$$c834f8.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE(<generated>)
org.pac4j.play.filters.SecurityFilter$$FastClassByGuice$$c834f8.apply(<generated>)
     com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:82)
     com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
     com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
[...]

It worked for former versions of Play (tested with 2.9).
Unfortunately I only know little about Java and even less about Scala.
I believe to understand what is missing but don't know how to fix it.
Henning
I expect the code to compile and run.
2024-09-27 Update:
In the meantime I cross-posted this in the Play Framework Discussion forum and got an answer from one of the core maintainers. The answer might also be interesting for the Pac4J-Play Team.
https://github.com/orgs/playframework/discussions/12867
Workaround: Use Scala 2.13 instead of Scala3.
https://github.com/mkurz/play-pac4j-java-demo/commit/121ede6d94b241a21b1ec8d8d9e508c3d6c2b821
